# "error:cannot acces com.hello.LibC","Class file for com.hello.LibC not Found"

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android.I use this [link](http://stevethai.wordpress.com/2010/08/04/android-helloworld-with-native-code-tutorial/) to run the NDK Project.

I follow all these steps from the given link.However during compilation in the command prompt it shows error like:

```
 $ javah com.hello.LibC
 error: cannot access com.hello.LibC
 class file for com.hello.LibC not found
 javadoc: error - Class com.hello.LibC not found.
 Error: No classes were specified on the command line.  Try -help.
```

please help me.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify the classpath using `-classpath PATH` option when running `javah` inside `bin` directory of your project:

```
$ javah -classpath classes/ com.hello.LibC
```

also you can specify the output directory using option `-d PATH`

```
$ javah -d ../jni -classpath classes/ com.hello.LibC
```